# UI-Router's resolve functions are only called once

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was going to use ui-routers resolve feature to inject some readiliy resolved promises into my controllers.

I used the example plnkr to make an example.
Consider these nested states: `route1` and `route1.list`.
I have a resolve function called `abc` defined on `route1`. Now when I navigate to `route1` for the first time, `abc` is called and will be resolved. Now when I navigate to `route1.list` and back to `route1`, `abc` is not called again.

http://plnkr.co/edit/mi5H5HKVAO3J6PCfKSW3?p=preview

I guess this is intentional, but consider this use-case:
the resolve function retrieves some data via http and should be refreshed/invalidated at some point, maybe on every state change. Is there some way to do this when using nested states?
If the resolve function was called on every inject I could implement it any way I want: Return the old, resolved promise or create a new one.

I have only briefly tested this, but if the states were not nested things would work as I expected. Giving up on nested states because of this stinks though. And having the resolve dependencies available in nested states is actually nice.

Comment: You can can watch for stateChange events in your controller.

Comment: Yes, but getting the resolved promises injected into the controller makes the code there much simpler. Also, I suppose this makes the state transitions perfect for wait animations.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Supplying the option `reload:true` to `go()` / `transtionTo()` / `ui-sref` does the trick :-)
Thanks to `Designing the Code` for pointing me in this direction. The solution is a bit different though, so I write up this answer.

Reload is [documented as follows](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.%24state):

> reload (v0.2.5) - {boolean=false}, If true will force transition even if the state or params have not changed, aka a reload of the same state. It differs from reloadOnSearch because you'd use this when you want to force a reload when everything is the same, including search params.

The direct way is to change every `ui-sref` link into something like this: `<a ui-sref="route1" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">`.

To avoid supplying the option at every link I wrote a decorator around `$state` (see also http://plnkr.co/edit/mi5H5HKVAO3J6PCfKSW3?p=preview):

```
 myapp.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate) {
    var originalTransitionTo = $delegate.transitionTo;
    $delegate.transitionTo = function(to, toParams, options) {
      return originalTransitionTo(to, toParams, angular.extend({
        reload: true
      }, options));
    };
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

Comment: when I use it with `$state.go()` from the child to the parent, I need to put `inherit: false` too in the options object, if not it still don't reload

Comment: And what if it happens as a result of the browser backbutton, not a link or button click where the reload: true can be specified?

Answer (score 11):

Try `$state.reload();`

It will force resolve the resolves again. Though think there is some issue related to this where controllers aren't reloaded. (ui.router n00b here as well)

Comment: Hey, you got me pointed in the right direction! It's even enough to specify the reload parameter then transitioning! E.g., `<a ui-sref="route1" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">`. Now, how do make that the default ...