# Parent controller instantiated each time a child view is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I am using ui-router and I have a configuration in which I am using a parent view which has a controller and child view which also have their own controllers.
Each time I navigate to one of the child views, the parent controller is instantiated again and therefore performs unnecessary requests to the server.
I want to be able to navigate between the child states and reuse the variables that were resolved by the parent controller.

How can I prevent the parent controller from being instantiated each time?

This is my routing config:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('researchLayoutEditor', {
        url: '/research/:researchId/layoutEditor/:orderInGroup',
        controller: 'layoutEditorController',
        controllerAs: 'layoutEditorCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'app/researchManagement/researchLayoutEditor/layoutEditor.html',
        redirectTo: 'researchLayoutEditor.slide',
        params: {
            group: 'A',
            orderInGroup: '0'
        },
        resolve: {
            researchLayout: function (researchesService, $stateParams) {
                return researchesService.getResearchLayout($stateParams.researchId, false);
            },
            research: function (researchesService, $stateParams) {
                return researchesService.getResearch($stateParams.researchId);
            }
        }
    }).state('researchLayoutEditor.slide', {
        url: '/textual',
        templateUrl: 'app/researchManagement/researchLayoutEditor/textSlide.html',
        controller: 'textSlideController',
        controllerAs: 'txtSlide'
    }).state('researchLayoutEditor.movie', {
        url: '/video',
        templateUrl: 'app/researchManagement/researchLayoutEditor/movieSlide.html',
        controller: 'movieSlideController',
        controllerAs: 'movieSlide',
        resolve: {
            movieCategories: function (utilsService) {
                return utilsService.getVideoCategories();
            }
        }
    }).state('researchLayoutEditor.memory', {
        url: '/memory',
        templateUrl: 'app/researchManagement/researchLayoutEditor/memorySlide.html',
        controller: 'memorySlideController',
        controllerAs: 'memorySlide'
    }).state('researchLayoutEditor.question', {
        url: '/question',
        templateUrl: 'app/researchManagement/researchLayoutEditor/questionSlide.html',
        controller: 'questionSlideController',
        controllerAs: 'questionSlide'
    });
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
    <div ui-view class="inner-content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might want to look at the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730868/ui-routers-resolve-functions-are-only-called-once

Comment: My problem is the opposite, I want to prevent reloading of the parent controller. The most weird thing is that the first child state (.slide) does not reload the parent controller on first visit to the page...

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://plnkr.co ?

Comment: I will try and give you an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying the most helpful way of debugging by elimination I found the problem which was the way I built the URL.
IN my parent state, I had the URL defined like this:

```
url: '/research/:researchId/layoutEditor/:orderInGroup',
```

when the orderInGroup parameter changed on each click on the child state. So the final URL looked like this for example:

> .../#/research/37/layoutEditor/1/video

Apparently, after changing the location of the "orderInGroup" parameter and putting it to the end of the URL

> .../#/research/37/layoutEditor/video/1

and moving the

```
                params: {
                    group: 'A',
                    orderInGroup: '0'
                }
```

object to the child states as well, the issue was resolved. 
So the URL configuration that finally worked looked like this (I moved the **/:orderInGroup** to child state):

```
$stateProvider
            .state('researchLayoutEditor', {
                url: '/research/:researchId/layoutEditor',
                controller: 'layoutEditorController',
                controllerAs: 'layoutEditorCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'app/researchManagement/researchLayoutEditor/layoutEditor.html',
                redirectTo: 'researchLayoutEditor.slide'
            })
            .state('researchLayoutEditor.movie', {
                url: '/video/:orderInGroup',
                templateUrl: 'app/researchManagement/researchLayoutEditor/movieSlide.html',
                controller: 'movieSlideController',
                controllerAs: 'movieSlide',
                params: {
                    group: 'A',
                    orderInGroup: '0'
                }
            })
            .state('researchLayoutEditor.slide', {
                url: '/textual/:orderInGroup',
                templateUrl: 'app/researchManagement/researchLayoutEditor/textSlide.html',
                controller: 'textSlideController',
                controllerAs: 'txtSlide',
                params: {
                    group: 'A',
                    orderInGroup: '0'
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using parent state as abstract,
here is a `plnkr` example [check it out](http://plnkr.co/edit/mXEFZh?p=info)